# DVWA: PHP module mysql: Missing php7.2 -sql module and can't find it

Tags: php, mysql, server

I am working on installing DVWA, which needs php-mysql. Linux is Debian.
My apache server is using php7.2 and I can't find php7.2-mysql,
however, I also have php7.4 installed and that has MySQL module.

How can I force apache to use php7.4?

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.2/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```